# Responsive label-value list/table flexibly adapting to the actual width of the rendered data

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm struggling with a CSS-layout problem I could find several solutions working under certain assumptions but so far I've been unable to find a solution leading to the desired result under all circumstances I am supposed to handle.

The basic situation seems simple at a first glance: I have a label-value list, which is basically a tabular structure, the first column containing a label, the second some text associated with the label. Something like this:

```css
.label-value-list {
    display: table;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.label-value-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.label-value-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="label-value-list">
    <div class="label-value-row">
        <div class="label-value-cell">Phone:</div>
        <div class="label-value-cell">+49 (0) 123 456789</div>
    </div>
    <div class="label-value-row">
        <div class="label-value-cell">Homepage:</div>
        <div class="label-value-cell">www.example.org</div>
    </div>
    <div class="label-value-row">
        <div class="label-value-cell">Prices starting from:</div>
        <div class="label-value-cell">€100</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the simple case where the structure fits nicely on the display's screen, a simple table-layout as outlined above leads to the desired result.

However, this approach does not lead to the desired result when the "table" is to wide for the display. In this case, I want the cells of the rows to be wrapped, i.e., each cell should be rendered on a separate line, pretty much the way it would be rendered with no CSS at all in the example above.

Now the problem is, that I can make no reasonable assumptions regarding the width of the "table" or its "cells", but I need the whole thing to adapt dynamically to the actual content of the cells.

Specifically, here are the requirements:

- I need a CSS-only solution. I know that I could easily achieve what I want if I could dynamically compute the widths of the data cells using JavaScript, but a need a solution not requiring JavaScript.
- I really cannot make any reasonable assumptions on the widths of the cells, neither absolute nor relative to table or the screen.
- I do not want to stretch the table across the whole screen unless it needs to. It should only take the width the columns actually require depending on their content (like in the `display: table` approach above).
- Considering only a single row, the wrapping rules are like this:

  - First, whenever possible, all text in a cell is to be place in one line.
  - If the two cells in a row do not fit in one line next to each other, then the two cells should be wrapped on separate lines.
  - If, any only if, the content of a cell wrapped this way still does not fit in one line entirely, then the text in that cell should be wrapped on multiple lines, too.
- Considering multiple rows, all rows should behave alike. I.e., if one row is to wide to fit entirely on the screen and, therefore, its cells need to be wrapped (according to the previous point), then the cells in all rows should be wrapped. It is not desirable that the cells in one row get wrapped while the cells in another rows do not.
- If no cell-wrapping is need, then the "label" and "value" cells should be aligned into columns, just like in a table.

The structure outlined in the example above is only an example. I can wrap the data in any amount of divs as long as the flow of the data is preserved, i.e., each "value" cell follows directly after it's associated "label" cell with now other "label" or "value" cells inbetween.

The hardest part of the problem is that I really know nothing about the widths of the "cells" of the "table" in advance. I cannot solve this problem using a `@media` query since the desired layout does not only depend on the display width but also on the width of the content actually rendered.

For the same reason, I cannot see a way to do this with a `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` approach, since in that case I'd either need to specify the widths of the cells, or the cells would not align in columns if no wrapping is needed. Same thing for `float` or `display: inline-block` cells.

Comment: Would you accept the scenario where the width of the label is set and anything larger than it's width wraps around? And width of the content is fluid? The main problem with your rules is that you want independently acting elements like DIVs to behave together like a table until one doesn't fit in the screen, then behave differently. This is easy with simple JS, by measuring the width of each row and adding classes to the ones that are larger than screen width. With CSS alone I would doubt it's possible.

Comment: That's the problem! I cannot make any reasonable assumptions about the widths of the columns. In one instance of the table, the label column may contain only short words like "Beer", "Wine", "Booze", but in another instance the label might contain something like "Boscarelli Vino Nobile di Montepulciano" or "Captain Morgan's Spiced Rum". If both columns fit in a single line without any wrapping, that's how they should be displayed.

Quite possibly I'm trying to do something impossible... but maybe I'm just not smart enough.

Comment: I don't want to say that it's impossible, but in 15 years of UI work I have never seen this done with CSS alone :) But I will follow your thread in case someone figures it out. It's a handy thing especially for fluid design.